# SpringBoot dynamic refresh is taking too long to load when the properties count is high

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud

SpringBoot is taking too long to load and refresh dynamic properties configured in a git file having around 12000 properties.

I have created a small PoC with config-server and client modules to demonstrate this behavior:
https://github.com/kirangodishala/spring-cloud-config-server-client

```
@RefreshScope
@RestController
class K8sRestController {

    @Autowired
    private K8sProperties k8sProperties;

    @RequestMapping("/k8s-props")
    K8sProperties getK8sProperties() {
        return k8sProperties;
    }
```

```
@Data
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "kubernetes")
public class K8sProperties {
  private List<ManagedAccount> accounts = new ArrayList<>();

  @Data
  public static class ManagedAccount {
    private String name;
    private ProviderVersion providerVersion;
    private String environment;
    private String accountType;
    ...
```

**application.yml under config-server**

```
server:
  port: 8888
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: https://github.com/kirangodishala/cloud-config.git
          basedir: /tmp/cd1
  application:
    name: clouddriver
```

I expected only few seconds for SpringBoot to discover that no changes are detected in the properties when /refresh end point is invoked. But instead it's taking approximately 7 minutes.

In our application, we have to check for the changes every 60sec but because of the long refresh cycles, CPU is in 100% use all the time.

Is there any fix for this issue?

Comment: We did not have this issue with Spring Boot 1.5.x. Any clue if this issue is going to be addressed by SpringBoot team? Or should we move away from SpringBoot to search for an alternate solution?

Answer (score 0):

May be you should have less properties under refresh scope.

Keeping everything under refresh scope going to harm your application. So better reduce the refresh scope to where it is always necessary.

Apart from that you should also check the connection between your server and git to make sure that is not experiencing low latency.

Hope this helps.

Comment: In other words, SpringBoot is not designed to handle such high number of properties? The account information is dynamic for us so we can’t remove them from refresh scope unless an alternative mechanism is available. There is no latency issue here, it’s purely the way SpringBoot handles the refresh that is costing the time and resources.